# Visitor Schengen Visa Denied 2 times. Can I apply for 15 days tourist visa and stay for 60 days?

Tags: indian-citizens, visa-refusals, switzerland

I had applied with Swiss embassy in New Delhi India through VFS for Visitor visa as I have to meet my brother and his family who lives in Geneva, Switzerland. I had applied for myself, wife and 3 year old son.

Travel dates 30/11/2017 to 01/02/2018.

My visa rejected first time saying 1.insufficient means of subsistence 2.no justification provided and 3. intention to leave member state can not be ascertained. (duration of stay was 79 days -15/11/17 to 01/02/18)

I applied second time (64 days duration-changed flights dates) and given bank statement with more than enough funds in bank statement for cause 1.

For cause 2, I gave return flight ticket to and fro India 30nov17 to 01Feb2018, train ticket to and fro Paris from Geneva 06to09Dec17 and return flight from geneva to munich germany 12/01/2018 to 13/01/2018.

I submitted hotel bookings for 4 days in Paris (09-12Dec17), 1 day in Interlaken (18Dec-19Dec2017), 2 days in Bern (22Dec-24Dec2017) and 1 day in Munich (12Jan2018-13Jan2018) as proof of intra-schengen travel. I gave them complete itinerary of my entire stay in Switzerland as I wanted to stay with my brother most of the time. (all bookings confirmed with confirmation emails from respective hotels).

Still they denied visa. What to do now?

Can I apply for 15 days tourist visa (at different consulate/embassy) and stay with my brother for 64 days?

Please suggest.

Warm Regards
Sumith G.

Comment: I suspect the duration is not the issue here. Item 3, intention to leave cannot be ascertained. This means even if you have enough money for the trip, they think you will overstay your visa. Since you have asked if you can apply for a 15 day stay but actually stay 54 days, perhaps their suspicion is justified?

Comment: For reason3, I gave declaration in covering letter that i will return to India on mentioned dates. I also added that my company has approved vacation for mentioned dates only as I have submitted letter from company and also submitted school leave approval letter for my son mentioning vacation dates. I also mentioned that I have aged parents to look after and I will return for them. Now my question is Can I apply to another embassy for 15 days tourist visa (with new bookings and itinerary) and stay for 60 days in Switzerland.

Comment: @SumithG "I gave declaration in covering letter that i will return to India on mentioned dates." Now that you're proposing to say you'll stay for two weeks when you're really staying for two months, do you understand why such a declaration is completely worthless?

Answer (score 5):

I wonder if there are translation problems with your question.

- If you *would* get a 15-day visa, you *could* stay only 15 days (first and last days count full). **Staying even one day longer would be a violation of your visa.** You *might* have to pay a fine when you leave. And any future application will be more difficult as well.
- You *must* apply for a visa at the embassy for main destination of your trip. If you lie in your application, your entry may be refused if they find out.
- A declaration that you will return is not enough to convince the visa officials that you plan to return. The aged parents *may* be a better explanation, but I don't know if that will be enough.